# String replace with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a way to replace what i'd call garbage text on a doc-xml file to replace with values

I have this program, that can grab a doc-xml to print out contracts, where the user only need to feed the program with a doc-xml file format where there will be some parameters that my program will replace with values

lets say I have this chunk of a contract format

```
The Contract {@ContractNumber} specified to the contractor {@ContractorName}....
```

My program looks for this parameters {@ContractNumber} and {@ContractorName} to replace with the Contract values, and i'm only asking the user to have it in a XML-DOC format, but sometimes the file it written like this

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0094616E" w:rsidRDefault="00AC620A"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>{@</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>ContractorNumber</w:t></w:r>
```

and sometime it will do what i'm really hoping for

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0094616E" w:rsidRDefault="0094616E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>{@Value1}</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

SO, what i'm looking for it a RegEx replace statement where i can get rid of all the garbage that can be found between open chars of my params ({@) and the closure of it (}) so it can find the entire word i'm looking to be replaced with the value assigned to it

Edit 1:

For a simpler understanding of my question, what i'm looking for it a ReGex that will Find everything that is between a `{@` and a subsequent `}` and when it finds `<>` delete them with everything within them so i have in the end `{@Param}` insted of `{@ <garbage/> Param <garbage/> }` or `{@Param <garbage/> }` or `{@Pa <garbage/> am}`

Edit 2:

So far, the most helpfull regex has been this one

```
{.*?@.*?}
```

Giving me a result like this

```
{</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>@Contrato</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Obrigado</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Adquisicion</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Import</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>e</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Acreditado</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ImporteLetras</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>O</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ficio</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>FechaOficio</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Gracia</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>M</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ensualidad-Gracia</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ImporteMensualidad</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>I</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>mporteMensualidadLetra</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>D</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ireccionAcreditada</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>EdoC</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ivilAcreditado</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>CiudadOri</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>genAcredi</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>t</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>a</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>do</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>IFE</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Acreditado</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Sexo</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Acreditado}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>EdoCivilAval</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>CiudadOrigenAval</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>IFEAval</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>S</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>e</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>xoAval</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>NumeroAmortizacion</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>DireccionAval</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ProgramaCredito</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Por</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>cComisionAper</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>tura</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}
```

now, i need is for the Regex to get rid of all those  and  that are between the characters, cant seem to find a way to delete those :S

Comment: Are you trying to make the regex to do parser's job?

Comment: since it's in XML, why not use an XML parser?

Comment: RomanR. actually, yes, thats pretty much it

jb. Already looking around that option, but since i'm using prettyh much pure strings, i think getting rid of the garbage with regex is much faster than xml parsing

Answer (score 1):

The first XML codeblock you provided does not contain a } character, so it already breaks your prerequisites. However, if you really want to go through with said solution, follow Jetti's advice; that is, generate a list of matches and perform a replace on each. I would have used the Regex expression

```
@"@{.*?}"
```

or

```
@"@{.*?ContractName.*?}"/@"@{.*?ContractorNumber.*?}"
```

but how you want to match it is really up to you and what you require.

Edit 1:

After reviewing your most recent edit and getting a better understanding of what you're looking for, I devised a slightly ugly but functional solution. Anyone with privileges are free to clean it up but I don't have time right now:

```
string yourstring = "{@</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Obrigado</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>}{@......}...";
Regex reg1 = new Regex(@"{.*?@.*?}");
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"<.*?>");

MatchCollection matches = reg1.Matches(yourstring);
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    // yeah.. this could be cleaned up. 
    names.Add((string)reg2.Replace(match.ToString(), ""));
}
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    yourstring = yourstring.Replace(matches[i].ToString(), names[i]);
}
```

I tried doing all of this in one foreach loop but match is readonly, and I can't think of a reasonable way to bypass that right now aside from a second run through. I've heard of recursive Regex methods, but I do not know much about them.

Comment: Updated; let me know if this works for you. It isn't the prettiest code, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(sourceString, @"{@ContractName}", myContractName);
Regex.Replace(sourceString, @"{@ContractNumber}", myContractNumber);
```

make sure to include the `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of your code.

Comment: The problem with this is that it would match {@ContractName} as well as {@ContractNumber} and replace it with the same value

Comment: @CJLopez  Well, what output did you get from it?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it. If the string to replace will be the same each time, you could just do

```
input.Replace("{@ContractNumber}","Actual Number");
```

If they can call it whatever they want, then you could do:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"{@[\w|\d]+}");
string input = "test {@name} this out";
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(input);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    // Look up the value or whatever based on m.Value
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `|` inside of `[]`, in fact that just adds `|` as a valid character. Also this doesn't handle XML in between. However whether that is possible in Regex is debatable.

Comment: @Guvante The way I understood the original question is that there is no xml and is just a string to designate a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "get rid of the garbage" and still have valid XML.

Here are some of the problems with this solution:

- Do you want to match `<w a="{@">` as part of string?
- What do you do when `</w>` is in between but not `<w>`?
- What do you do when `<w>` is in between but not `</w>`?

It sounds like you are either going to have to clean up your input somehow, or do it the hard way using an XML parsing library and some state.

Comment: actually, what i'm looking for it a ReGex that will 

Find everything that is between a `{@` and a subsequent `}` and when it finds `<>` delete them with everything within them so i have in the end `{@Param}` insted of `{@ <garbage/> Param <garbage/> }` or `{@Param <garbage/> }` or `{@Pa <garbage/> am}`

Comment: @CJLopez: Then you won't have valid XML, you can delete whole nodes and be okay, but randomly deleting a `</garbage>` would break it. In fact in your first example `<w:t>` is before `{@`, but `</w:t>` is after, if you deleted `</w:t>` you would no longer have valid XML (unless you just got lucky and also deleted enough matching `<w:t>` later in the section)

Comment: Luckily for me, it wont kill it :D